# Creating tabs for an icon in AppShell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create the following effect in my Xamarin Forms 5 app and I need some guidance on how to achieve it.

In my flyout footer, I want to display two icons. One of them is the settings icon and when the user taps it, I want to send the user to a tabbed page -- see below:

[image]

How do I define tabs in my `AppShell` footer and tie them to this icon?

Here's my `AppShell`:

```
<TabBar>
   <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
</TabBar>

<FlyoutItem Title="Home">
    <FlyoutItem.Icon>
        <FontImageSource
            FontFamily="MISHRP"
            Glyph="{StaticResource HomeIcon}"
            Color="White" />
    </FlyoutItem.Icon>
    <Tab Title="Feed">
        <ShellContent Route="Feed" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate home:Feed}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Products">
        <ShellContent Route="Products" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate home:Products}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="History">
        <ShellContent Route="History" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate home:History}"/>
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="School">
    <FlyoutItem.Icon>
        <FontImageSource
            FontFamily="MISHRP"
            Glyph="{StaticResource SchoolIcon}"
            Color="White" />
    </FlyoutItem.Icon>
    <Tab Title="Courses">
        <ShellContent Route="Courses" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate school:Courses}"/>
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>

<Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Grid RowDefinitions="120" ColumnDefinitions="150, 150">
         <Image
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            Margin="50,0,0,0">
               <Image.Source>
                  <FontImageSource
                     FontFamily="MISHRP"
                     Glyph="{StaticResource SettingsIcon}"
                     Color="White"/>
               </Image.Source>
         </Image>
         <Image
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            Margin="0,0,30,0">
               <Image.Source>
                  <FontImageSource
                     FontFamily="MISHRP"
                     Glyph="{StaticResource PowerIcon}"
                     Color="White"/>
               </Image.Source>
         </Image>
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
```

IntelliSense is not allowing me to define `<Tab>`'s inside a `<Grid>`. How do I link this icon to tabs?

Comment: "How do I define tabs in my AppShell footer and tie them to this icon?" Is not clear what you want to achieve exactly ? Why would you want to define tabs in footer?

Comment: I want the settings icon to take user to a page with 3 bottom tabs.

Comment: Do you mean navigating to new page with tabes when clicking on settings icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your are looking for .
First use `Image.GestureRecognizers`

For the showing of the FLyout in Settings use  `Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;`

The easy way to use Tabs in the Settings if you want is to use a TabbedPage

And for the Tabs in Settings.xaml `Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"`

AppShell.xaml

```
<Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid RowDefinitions="30" ColumnDefinitions="150, 150">
                <Image
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
                Source="Settings.png"
                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        Margin="50,0,0,0" 
                    >
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <Image
            Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
                 Source="Power.png"
        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
        Margin="0,0,30,0">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        </Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Settings), typeof(Settings));
    
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("Settings");
     
        Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;
     
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer with an Gif how it looks like if you use TabbedPage for Settings

Comment: @Sam did you solved the question

Comment: This kind of works but the problem is that I have a back button on top of the page. Even in your example, I see that back button. I really wanted this to behave like any other page in my `FlyoutTemplate` where I get a page with tabs at the bottom but no back button and still have the burger menu icon to access the flyout. Is this not possible? BTW, I tried hiding the back button with `NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(SettingsPage, false);` but this gives me "SettingsPage is a type, which is not valid in the given context" error.

Answer (score 0):

Add Clicked event to the image.

```
<Image
       Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.Column="1"
       HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
       Margin="0,0,30,0">
       <Image.Source>
                  <FontImageSource
                     FontFamily="MISHRP"
                     Glyph="{StaticResource PowerIcon}"
                     Color="White"/>
       </Image.Source>
       <Image.GestureRecognizers>
           <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="OnImageNameTapped"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
       </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

then in the xaml.cs , after creating your tabbedpage with your three tabs

```
void OnImageNameTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
         {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabbedPage1());  
            // or await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new TabbedPage1());
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
         {
           throw ex;
         }
    }
```

Comment: I'm able to open my tabbed page with this approach but I have two problems to solve here: 1. The home page of my application is also a tabbed page which are defined in `AppShell`. When I click and go to the "Settings" page, the tabs from the home page are still visible. The tabs for the "Settings" page are displayed right above the tabs from home page. They should no longer be there. 2. The flyout stays open. I see the "Settings" page opening right behind it but the flyout stays open. I'm not sure why I'm getting this totally different behavior here.

Comment: I updated the original post to show the whole `AppShell` XAML code so that you can see how it's structured. Both "Home" and "School" flyout items also define tabs right in `AppShell`.

Comment: what if you did Navigation.PushModelAsync?